# When to use what centripetal acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, centripetal-force

There are two equations for it: $a_c = v^2 / r$ and $a_c = \omega^2 / r$.

It seems like they give me different values. I don't know when to use which. Can you explain?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an incorrect formula and is not really conceptual.

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation is the radial acceleration which is equal to $v^2/r$ and second equation is $\omega^2r$; both equations are the same because the angular velocity $\omega=v/r$.